# How should I handle downloading extra files for my app?

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a .net desktop app and there are add-on files to the app and I would like the user to be able to download them when needed from the app, So how should I handle this, I was thinking maybe I could set up an ftp server and grab the files from there but I want to know the best practice for this or the most efficient solution

Comment: Entirely depends on your use case. There are many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is typically the easiest solution. I would set up a website and host the files, and then have the application download them as needed.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile("https://your-domain.com/application/foo.bar", "foo.bar");
}
```